# SSH Client with Paramiko: avoid multiple connections

Tags: python, linux, ssh, kivy, paramiko

I'm trying to do a simple App in Kivy, where different devices could read and write a txt file using an SSH connection to a Linux Server with OpenSSH.
Being a simple App my idea was simply to avoid multiple SSH connection, so I edited the file `limits.conf` in `/etc/security` adding the line:

```
   user    hard    maxlogins    1
```

in this way I can avoid that 2 devices could write the same file at the same time. If a test the connection with `Putty` or with another Android SSH client everything works (I can only have one connection at time) BUT if I use Paramiko I get a strange behaviour: I can have multiple connection at the same time!
This is my code:

```
# main.py

import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.0")
__version__ = "0.1"

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import paramiko

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    def open_ssh(self):
        try:
            self.ssh.connect("192.168.0.200", 22, "user", "password", timeout = 1)
            self.sftp = self.ssh.open_sftp()
            self.ids.output.text = "SSH On"
        except:
            self.ids.output.text = "TX/RX Error"

    def close_ssh(self):
        self.sftp.close()
        self.ssh.close()
        self.ids.output.text = "SSH Off"

class ParamikoApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = RootWidget()            
        return root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ParamikoApp().run()


# paramiko.kv 

<RootWidget>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    Label:
        id: output

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: open_button
            text: "Open SSH"
            on_press: root.open_ssh()

        Button:
            id: close_button
            text: "Close SSH"
            on_press: root.close_ssh()
```

So my question is:
There's something missing in my connection code or Paramiko works in a different way from a standard SSH client?
I also tried to use the `MaxSessions` setting in the `sshd_config` file and the `set_keepalive` parameter in Paramiko with no lucky..

Answer (score 1):

> in this way I can avoid that 2 devices could write the same file at the same time.

I think you need to take a step back and think about what problem you are *really* trying to solve. There are hundreds to thousands of different ways I can think of to have multiple clients log data. It is a **totally solved** problem. But none of those ways involve "single-user SSH". You might find the "answer" for your problem today, but you will certainly run into another arbitrary roadblock tomorrow.

The industry standard is to have your client talk HTTPS to your server. You should have very good reasons for going against the flow here. Web servers are far more scalable, simpler, and flexible than SSH servers. If you are cheap, you can get free certs from Lets Encrypt.

You can solve your "one at a time" problem at many levels:

- Run a single-threaded HTTP server (so connections wait in the OS).
- Write your own locking (so your app does the waiting)
- Just use a database (so you don't even have to think about locking).

Comment: I know that the secret of every professional client-server application is a real database engine, but for now, being my second litte amateur App with a target of 100/200 people, a simple TXT file it's enough.
Anyway, in my personal to-do list for bigger Apps, there's Flask + SQLite..

Comment: Agreed, don't fix what ain't broke. But using SSH for RPC (and subsequently trying to reduce concurrency) is broken.  Any HTTP server/proxy supports limiting concurrency as a first-class feature.